# Future Builder error getting user data from firebase firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, future, builder

I am using firebase firestore to get data of loggined user but get error that type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
this is my code :

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('buyers');
    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).get(),
      builder:
          (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {

        if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              elevation: 2,
              backgroundColor: lightblue,
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text(
                'Profile',
                style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 4),
              ),
              actions: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Icon(CupertinoIcons.moon),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.015,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 64,
                    backgroundColor: lightpurple,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(data['profileImage']),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    data['fullName'],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    data['email'],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: Divider(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    thickness: 2,
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
                  title: Text('Settings'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.phone),
                  title: Text('Phone'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart),
                  title: Text('Cart'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(CupertinoIcons.cart),
                  title: Text('Orders'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.logout),
                  title: Text('Logout'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(child: Text("Something went wrong"));
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
      },
    );
  }
```

Error:
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>#9a869):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>> FutureBuilder:file:///C:/Users/Haier/AndroidStudioProjects/Ecommerce-App-Complete/ecommerce_app/lib/View/nav_screens/account_screen.dart:20:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

Comment: `Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;` may be returning null

Comment: Can you give share the firebase database image

Comment: can you give me solution saad?

Comment: it is also saying snapshot is in object format